# Compare two ndarrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two ndarrays. First ndarray has string in one column and float values in another column. Second ndarray contains only a column of string values.

For eg:

```
   Array1                Array2
"abc"     1.000          "abc"
"fsfds"  -5.000          "qw"
"svs"     2.094          "svs"
"dfdsge"  3.348          "dd"
```

My question is, how can I compare matching string values from Array1 and Array2 then return corresponding float values from Array1?

I tried set(Array1) & set(Array2) to find unique elements but don't know how to extract float values. Is there a function in numpy?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the dtype and shape of these arrays?  Depending on how it's constructed, `Array1` could be 1d with 2 fields, or be 2d with a string dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj for both ndarray I have assigned object as dtype

Comment: Well then `Array1[:,0]` should be 1d array that can be compared to `Array2`.  I"m not sure how making them `object dtype` affects the comparison.  We'd have play around with it.

Comment: Is it better to assign dtype as str and int for Array1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to turn your example into arrays is to copy-n-paste it as a multiline string and use `genfromtxt` to parse it:

```
In [344]: txt=b'''"abc"     1.000          "abc"
     ...: "fsfds"  -5.000          "qw"
     ...: "svs"     2.094          "svs"
     ...: "dfdsge"  3.348          "dd"  '''

In [346]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
Out[346]: 
array([(b'"abc"',  1.   , b'"abc"'), (b'"fsfds"', -5.   , b'"qw"'),
       (b'"svs"',  2.094, b'"svs"'), (b'"dfdsge"',  3.348, b'"dd"')],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', 'S5')])
```

With `dtype=None` it deduces column dtype, and creates a structured array.  I can split that into 2 arrays, one with 2 fields, the other with 1. These are all 1d.

```
In [347]: arr1, arr2 = _[['f0','f1']], _['f2']
In [348]: arr1
Out[348]: 
array([(b'"abc"',  1.   ), (b'"fsfds"', -5.   ), (b'"svs"',  2.094),
       (b'"dfdsge"',  3.348)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
In [349]: arr2
Out[349]: 
array([b'"abc"', b'"qw"', b'"svs"', b'"dd"'],
      dtype='|S5')
```

You are little unclear about how you want to compare the text columns.  An easy one that looks reasonable with this data is just element by element, the simple `==`.

```
In [350]: arr1['f0']==arr2
Out[350]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

With this boolean mask I can easily select the elements of `arr1`:

```
In [351]: arr1[_]
Out[351]: 
array([(b'"abc"',  1.   ), (b'"svs"',  2.094)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

Lets see if I can turn these into object arrays.

---

```
In [372]: array1 = np.array(arr1.tolist(),dtype=object)
In [373]: array2 = np.array(arr2.tolist(),dtype=object)
In [374]: array1
Out[374]: 
array([[b'"abc"', 1.0],
       [b'"fsfds"', -5.0],
       [b'"svs"', 2.094],
       [b'"dfdsge"', 3.348]], dtype=object)
In [375]: array2
Out[375]: array([b'"abc"', b'"qw"', b'"svs"', b'"dd"'], dtype=object)
```

We can get the same mask:

```
In [376]: array1[:,0]==array2
Out[376]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [377]: array1[_,:]
Out[377]: 
array([[b'"abc"', 1.0],
       [b'"svs"', 2.094]], dtype=object)
```

Another way to get a mask:

```
In [378]: np.in1d(array2,array1[:,0])
Out[378]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

In this case it produces the same thing

Actually to get the rows of `array1` that are in `array2` (in any order), we need to switch the order:

```
In [389]: np.in1d(array1[:,0],array2[[1,0,3,2]])
Out[389]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Look at `in1d` and the related array `set` functions for more ideas and details.

In any case, use `field` or column selection to get the 1d array of strings that can be compared to the strings in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array comparison as your index for the first dimension to select the rows you want. I'm not sure exactly how you have an ndarray containing both strings and floats, but here's an example where we set it so the first and last rows have the same value in the first column.

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.random.randn(4, 2)
array_2 = np.random.randn(4)
array_2[3] = array_1[3, 0]
array_2[0] = array_1[0, 0]

print(array_1, array_2)
print(array_1[array_1[:, 0] == array_2, 1])
```

This gives

```
[[ 0.76170733 -1.40708366]
 [-1.42535617 -1.03982291]
 [ 0.67999753 -0.92733875]
 [ 0.96474552 -1.95639871]]
[ 0.76170733  0.95046454  0.1548689   0.96474552]
[-1.40708366 -1.95639871]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that list comprehension can do the trick here:

```
Output=[i[1] for i in Array1 if i[0] in Array2]
```

Comment: It just returned the initial letter of string but thank you

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm edditing it so that it properly works